# Need help making cloth-like object for dragon wings

Tags: modeling

I have the basic skeleton of a dragon's wing, but how can I best make the fabric-like material for the actual wing? I will be animating it. I would like to avoid using cloth simulation, as I will be taking this model from Blender to Unity/Unreal Engine.[image]

[image: reference photo]

Comment: hello, your question is a bit too broad, and you should show a reference image, but you probably need to use the Translucent node in your setup

Comment: @moonboots is this better

Comment: so I guess you need to have a topology that follows this kind of shape, also you need to put the Solidify modifier at the right place, maybe share what you've done so far so that people don't have to redo it from scratch? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: I’m out atm, I’ll do that when I get home

Comment: this is what i have so far @moonboots https://pasteall.org/blend/c9c1de61b3e04337974cdbb86f20b33d

Comment: you'd better join everything within one object only, then bridge between the fingers to create the skin, subdivide in order to have topology, and test how it works with an armature. See how people did it, for example: https://blenderartists.org/t/dragon-animation-project/624655 ... the only problem I see is how to avoid overlapping faces for the skin

Comment: seems to work perfecty. haven't tried with armature yet, but this is great! thx so much ur always really helpful @moonboots

Comment: oh ok great, your question was a bit too broad, as I say you may meet problem when you'll parent your object to the armature and you'll bend the wings, as it could make the skin faces overlap, you'll tell  ;)

Comment: could a subsurf modifier fix that potential problem?

Comment: you'll need a Subsurf anyway, unless you want a lowpoly result. First try and you'll see if it happens, then you'll find a solution

Comment: i do want low poly, im making a game and this model is a stand-in until i have time to make proper models

Comment: oh ok so you won't be able to use a Subsurface in your game, you'll have to apply it

Comment: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/856199460068917293/876872842984169543/unknown.png @moonboots what have I done wrong

Comment: sorry I can't see anything, your link doesn't seem to work

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/a4815e10ef4b4b409e2a07387fe08060

Comment: I don't think that your topology is correct, if your skin is connected to your finger it's probably better to give it thickness, also you have triangulated, i'm not sure why, maybe follow some tutos on how to model a dragon, it will help to see how to do

Comment: ok ill do that.